# Как правильно сверстать блок с декорацией?

Tags: css, вёрстка, svg, адаптивная-верстка

Как правильнее сверстать такой блок? а именно декорацию. Трансформом, бордерами, фоном или svg и как это реализовать? как бы есть желание стремиться к идеалу, чтобы декор не разваливался если много текста но насколько это важно в случаях с такими айтемами?

Кидаю код html для примера, хотя не вижу в этом особого смысла в том то и вопрос как лучше начинать верстать чтобы лишнего кода не плодить))

```
<div class="item__s1-descr">
    <div class="item__s1-title">ВЫСОКАЯ ДАЛЬНОСТЬ ХОДА</div>
    <div class="item__s1-descr">дальность хода на одном заряде аккумулятора до 50 м</div>
</div>
```

а вот в css загвоздка, мои мысли либо фоном задать и все фиксированное либо изощряться с трансформами и бордерами что не есть круто по моему, либо как то svg внедрить но тут как раз я не силен, по тому и спрашиваю как реализовать правильнее!

[image: ПРИМЕР]

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: Наваяю то что у меня получилось в результате и скину чтоб была польза)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin тут хотя бы заголовок  немного детализирует задачу. О проблеме в целом опубликовал вопрос: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5298/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e

Comment: Сверстал фиксировано, по ширине блок не большой по тому при изменении разрешения просто положил их в стопку, а по высоте получилось что есть лимит на текст, но в моем случае его достаточно, было бы идеально это все сделать универсальным чтобы оно растягивалось как угодно, ни иконок ни самой рамки в svg не было, векторизовать можно как вариант но не стал, по сути если высота айтема меняется то они встают не так как надо в моем случае, Спасибо за ответы людям особенно Alexandr_T с svg буду работать учиться делать более сложные вещи. Если с вопроса нет никому пользы удаляйте.

Comment: @junior-web-dev заглядывайте сюда. В ближайшее время дам более развернутый ответ, как легче и быстрее освоить svg для практического применения в верстке.

Comment: Большое спасибо, буду ждать)

Answer (score 4):

Иконку, конечно лучше добавить svg.
 Контур вокруг текста лучше сделать средствами CSS, например с помощью `clip-path`.
Так как в SVG нет автоматического переноса текста в отличии от HTML, то придется для каждой строчки svg текста использовать теги переноса `<tspan>`

[Вот выборка постов на нашем сайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=clip-path) по `clip-path`

**Почитайте и тут же пробуйте сделать свою форму, приведите в вопросе попытки своего кода.** Иначе сейчас ваш вопрос заминусуют, как не имеющий конкретики.

Answer (score 4):

я бы так это сделал

> Синий фон добавлен что бы показать что ни чего не мешает ..

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  background: lightblue;
}

.parent {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  perspective: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 60px;
}

.child-top,
.child-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  transform: rotateY(-10deg);
}

.child-bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 0;
}

.child-top:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 400px;
  border-bottom: 100px solid #FFE344;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  z-index: -1;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
}

.child-bottom:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 400px;
  border-top: 100px solid #FFE344;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  z-index: -1;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-top">
    <h4>высокая дальность хода</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="child-bottom">
    <p>до 50 метров</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Дэмо : [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть у трансформ одна плохая особенность, он размывает детали =( если только сделать так же, но текст отдельным блоком то норм, но задача была не в том чтобы сделать маску, а в том чтобы сделать сложную рамку адаптивно и с возможностью растягивания без искажения, и просто хотел узнать как бы сверстали более опытные люди такой блок с декорацией как на картинке (рамка сложной формы с не соединенными линиями), но как отметили многие - вопрос задан расплывчато) Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Несколько раз мне попадался этот вопрос. Пару раз прицеливался, начинал, и бросал эту затею. А здесь, думаю, дай все же немного поизвращаюсь на чистом css. И вот, собственно, что получилось. В итоге полное извращение :))

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
  min-width: 600px;
  min-height: 350px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .container {
    max-height: 450px;
  }
}

.block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 10%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: darkgray;
  clip-path: polygon(1% 40%, 15% 5%, 80% 0%, 100% 60%, 90% 100%, 15% 90%, 0% 60%);
}

.block:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  height: calc(100% - 2px);
  width: calc(100% - 2px);
  background-color: white;
  clip-path: polygon(1% 40%, 15% 5%, 80% 0%, 100% 60%, 90% 100%, 15% 90%, 0% 60%);
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 40%;
  height: 20%;
  width: calc(12% + 5px);
  background-color: white;
}

.icon:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 10%;
  bottom: calc(50% - 1px);
  width: 50%;
  border-top: 3px dashed darkgray;
  border-bottom: 3px dashed darkgray;
  border-left: 3px dashed darkgray;
  border-radius: 50% 0 0 50%;
}

.icon:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -3px;
  bottom: 10%;
  top: calc(50% - 2px);
  width: 50%;
  border-top: 3px dashed darkgray;
  border-bottom: 3px dashed darkgray;
  border-right: 3px dashed darkgray;
  border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;
}

.icon__dots {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: calc(50% - 20px);
  width: 18px;
  border-bottom: 3px dashed darkgray;
}

.icon__dots:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: calc(0% - 5px);
  left: 0;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: darkgray;
}

.icon__dots:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(0% - 3px);
  right: calc(0% - 5px);
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: darkgray;
}

.ico {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
  left: 20%;
  right: 0;
  height: 80%;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: darkgray;
  border-radius: 70% 70% 100% 100%;
  clip-path: polygon( 0% 0%, 90% 0%, 97% 30%, 95% 50%, 93% 60%, 88% 70%, 85% 75%, 83% 77%, 80% 80%, 70% 90%, 54% 99%, 46% 99%, 30% 90%, 20% 80%, 17% 77%, 15% 75%, 12% 70%, 7% 60%, 5% 50%, 3% 30%, 10% 0);
}

.ico:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  height: calc(100% - 6px);
  width: calc(100% - 6px);
  border-radius: 70% 70% 100% 100%;
  background-color: white;
  clip-path: polygon( 0% 0%, 90% 0%, 97% 30%, 95% 50%, 93% 60%, 88% 70%, 85% 75%, 83% 77%, 80% 80%, 70% 90%, 54% 99%, 46% 99%, 30% 90%, 20% 80%, 17% 77%, 15% 75%, 12% 70%, 7% 60%, 5% 50%, 3% 30%, 10% 0);
}

.ico:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 35%);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 40%;
  width: 50%;
  border: 3px solid darkgray;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 15%;
  right: 20%;
  bottom: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 4vw;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #ce9200;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

p {
  font-size: 3vw;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: darkgray;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-top: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="text">
      <h1>Высокая дальность хода</h1>
      <p>дальность хода на одном заряде аккумулятора до 50 м</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="icon">
    <div class="icon__dots"></div>
    <div class="ico"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```